# Auto input measurements to Excel

Tags: excel, image, hardware, hardware-interface

I'm looking for an input tool (like a wireless pen) that can be used to measure images from a surface that will then auto input the data into an excel spreadsheet. Anyone familiar with type of hardware? I've been doing some searching around but haven't had a lot of luck finding something that can do that.

I'd also be interested in software that could take an image allow me to use my mouse to draw a box around that image and input the measurements into an excel spreadsheet as well.

Just curious if anyone has come across anything like either of these options.
Thanks a ton!!!
-Deke

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a good answer to your main question but for the second part; you can use **Acrobat Reader DC**'s "Measure" tools to set a scale and get sizing and volume measurements from a PDF file. We use that all the time for building estimates. Best of luck